# Which Standard Visitor visa should I apply for?

Tags: bookings, standard-visitor-visas

My husband is in UK on a 3-month Business visa. Now I want to apply for a visa to visit him for 7-10 days.

What visa should I apply for?

I don't have a marriage certificate but do have an affidavit to prove we are married. Also the trip will be sponsored by myself. Stay will be at his accommodation currently.

Should I book tickets before the visa, will that make any difference to the decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon what you wrote, you should create an account at [visa4uk](http://visa4uk.fco.gov.uk) and use it to apply for a '[Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview)'.  Your husband does not qualify as a family sponsor, so you would fill out the form like in this image...

[image]

**Should i book tickets before the visa will that make any difference on the decision?**

It is a very bad idea to purchase tickets in advance of a visa application. It tells the decision-maker that you did not read [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) and probably do not understand the rules.  You also undergo the risk of cancelling tickets in the event your application is not successful or it takes a long time for them to reach a decision.

Here's a screen shot of the relevant [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf)...

[image]

And finally, in the remarks section of the form, you put down that you are visiting your husband and include his entry clearance number.  If you have problems substantiating your marriage, then use 'partner' everywhere.  Your husband/'partner' should write a letter to the consulate supporting your visit (naming you as wife or partner) and you should include it with your application.  They prefer wet signatures if possible.  It's ok to explain in the remarks section why you do not have a license as long as the explanation is reasonable.

Comment: do i need a marriage certificate or an affidavit then?

Comment: @Alia answer updated for you

Comment: Its been just a 1.5yrs we have been married and both of us are working. Hence we did not got a chance to visit our native much to get the marriage registered.  Will this be reasonable?

Comment: @Alia, it's ok, but flesh it out a bit more. :)